# redirect low bandwidth web site for dial up users

Tags: html, bandwidth

I have been searching to see if it is possible to include a script that will push a low bandwidth version of a web site for those who have dial up. There are two sites (one with lots of JS, images, code, etc.) and a site that is limited. I would like those who have dial up to view that page instead of the slow loading page.

Is there a script for this?
Thanks.

Comment: What would be the point? A user with a low bandwidth waits for a long time to load your page. Then you redirect him, so he has to wait even longer?

Comment: I would like to know if there is a way to bypass our main page if the user has dial up service and redirect them to our low bandwidth page. There were instances where individuals complained that our site took forever for them to load because of java script, images, lots of code, etc. 

So are you telling me that this cannot be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could send the client a tiny ajax script that calls back the server. The process can be timed and you can make your decision based on the result time. However some time will be lost in the process, but the time saved for the slow browser could be significant.